# HD scan in Mountain Lion

Tags: disk-utility

I suspect a faulty drive. Anything that could perform a hardware scan (bad sectors?) built into Mountain Lion or available for free off the 'net?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Disk Utility. Click Verify Disk to see if the disk is faulty.

My last HD failed after a year of use. The past month has made the computer really slow. Most HD manufacturer gives out a replacement if it fails within 3 years though.

Comment: Maybe try doing the verify (or repair) off an external drive or the recovery partition.

Comment: Yep - forgot to mention, did it from the recovery partition.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.titanium.free.fr has a free utility called Onyx which runs cron jobs, toggles hidden prefs and has many other uses but most importantly in this case runs a SMART test on the HD automatically at startup. I have used it for several years and recommend it. It also has a section for UNIX man info as well. Great little free doodad.

Answer (score 0):

Smart Utility is truly excellent and is far better than Disk Utility at spotting hardware issues. You can try it for free. http://www.volitans-software.com/smart_utility.php